# AngularJS ng-hide / ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

Im learning about AngularJS but I have a problem with the "ng-hide" directive, its doesnt work.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prueba ng-hide/ng-show</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p ng-hide="true">I'm hidden</p>
    <p ng-show="true">I'm shown</p>
</body>
```

And this is my script for Angular

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js (of course, between "script" tags)

Comment: where does your app initialized? it should have `ng-app` directive to make it working,,

Comment: Thanks, but I have that directive, only that I dont post all the code. But I can resolve the problem. Was a directive before that, I write it bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your application. 
Add `ng-app` to your html

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
...
```

Then create your app module

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have that directive, only that I dont post all the code. But I can resolve the problem. Was a directive before that, I write it bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You aren't bootstrapping your application.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app"> <!-- You're missing this -->
    <p ng-hide="true">I'm hidden</p>
    <p ng-show="true">I'm shown</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); // You're also probably missing this
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9aG4wdc88pSomIMELwx4)**

Comment: Thanks, but I have that directive, only that I dont post all the code. But I can resolve the problem. Was a directive before that, I write it bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently you haven't compiled page by angular compiler, for that you need add `ng-app` directive(basically it takes module name, but in sample you should do only this to make) it working.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="">
    <p ng-hide="true">I'm hidden</p>
    <p ng-show="true">I'm shown</p>
</body>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wDNDzWT1SeJu5Htm1ec7?p=preview)

Technically you should create a module and add components to that module (in enterprise world).

Comment: Thanks, but I have that directive, only that I dont post all the code. But I can resolve the problem. Was a directive before that, I write it bad. Thanks

Comment: @JoseR.Chacón may I know, why you are copy and pasting same comment for all?

Answer (score 0):

Jose you have to tell your page that it is an Angular app

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
```

and you have to create your app in the JS file:

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have that directive, only that I dont post all the code. But I can resolve the problem. Was a directive before that, I write it bad. Thanks